# Reading items from a dataset

Tags: r, rstudio

I download a file which in every column contains an item or empty cells in csv format. When i write the code:

```
groceries_data = groceries_data <- read.transactions("groceries.csv")
```

Surprisingly I see the result :

```
summary(groceries_data)
transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
 9835 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
 8146 columns (items) and a density of 0.0004401248
```

but when i write the code

```
groceries_data = read.transactions("groceries.csv",sep=",")
```

Then the result is:

```
summary(groceries_data)
transactions as itemMatrix in sparse format with
 9835 rows (elements/itemsets/transactions) and
 169 columns (items) and a density of 0.02609146
```

which is the right result from the book but logically it should work with the first command and not by the second. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

That function isn't intended to work with CSV by default. See `help(read.transactions)` - for the `sep` argument it states:

> a character string specifying how fields are separated in the data file. The default ("") splits at whitespaces.

So unless you tell it to split on comma, it is splitting on every white space. If you've got spaces in many product names, then every word of every product name will become a column.

By specifying the `sep` argument as a comma, it's importing the CSV file correctly, as you wanted.